# Passing optional data to REST API

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

We have a Desktop Client and a REST API.  For several POST REST calls, we want to pass a correlation GUID from the Client to the API that is used to correlate log entries related to the same user interaction.

This parameter is optional and must be backwards compatible, not failing if it is omitted.  What options are there to pass this in while keeping code clean?

I'm concerned that if I put it:

- In the header, it means receiving a HttpRequestMessage and manually extracting it, the URL parameters and the body content in each API call.
- In the URL, it may not hit the correct route if the parameter is missing (eg. backward compatibility.)
- In the body, it pollutes the model as the parameter is related to the system rather than the data.

For example, an existing method is:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage SaveData([FromBody]DataModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

I feel like I've missed something.  Where is the best place for it?

Answer (score 1):

It's strongly depends on your api `action` either is `Get` or `Post`, if you using Get action you can put your parameter in header and also you can use default value for your parameter in `route` configuration like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { **id = RouteParameter.Optional** }
        );
```

If you are using `Post` action you can easily use default value in method prototype :
Example :

```
[HttpPost]
public object DoSomething(int logEntryIndex=0)
{
    return "Something";
}
```

But I'm strongly recommend you always use an object as your parameter. Then it's so easy to add any property [as a new parameter] to class and you never would had these kind of problems

```
    [HttpPost]
    public object DoSomething(MyParam parameter)
    {
        return "Something";
    }

    public class MyParam
    {
      // prop1
      // prop2
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the correlation GUID from URL as optional parameter so that it will be backward compatible, clean and will not pollute your data models. For example:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Contact/{correlationId:Guid?}")]
public HttpResponseMessage SaveData([FromBody]DataModel model, [FromUri] Guid? correlationId = null)
{
    //code to handle request
}
```

From MSDN:

> You can make a URI parameter optional by adding a question mark to the
>   route parameter. If a route parameter is optional, you must define a
>   default value for the method parameter.

More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional)

Hope it helps.